# MySQL updating 2 columns with random and conditional value based on that random

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-update, mysql-5.7

I have such a table, with dates in format YYYY-MM-DD

```
id | state_id | created_on  | closed_on  |
1  | 1        | 2020-02-19  | NULL       |
2  | 2        | 2020-01-02  | 2020-01-03 |
3  | 1        | 2020-01-05  | NULL       |
4  | 4        | 2020-02-07  | 2020-02-08 |
4  | 3        | 2020-02-20  | NULL       |
```

I need to update the STATE with a random state between 2 and 6 WHERE

- *state_id* is 1 OR *state_id* is 3
- *created_on* is in the past

I can do so with this (**IT WORKS PERFECTLY**):

```sql
UPDATE table SET state_id = FLOOR(2 + rand() * 6) 
WHERE created_on < CURRENT_DATE()
AND (state_id=1 OR state_id=3)
```

What I need to do additionally in the same update, would be to set *closed_on*:

- NULL if *the new random state* is 3
- `CURRENT_DATE()` if *the new random state* IS anything but 3

I thought about using `SET @newState = FLOOR(2 + rand() * 6)`, but this way all the records would have the same *state_id*

is it possible to update with different values?

something like this

```sql
UPDATE table SET state_id = FLOOR(2 + rand() * 6), closed_on = IF(new_state_id = 3, NULL, CURRENT_DATE())
WHERE created_on < CURRENT_DATE()
AND (state_id=1 OR state_id=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could self-join the table with a subquery that computes the random number, so you can reuse that value in the outer query:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, floor(2 + rand() * 6) rnd
    from mytable 
    where state_id in (1, 3)
    and created_on < CURRENT_DATE()
) t1 using(id)
set 
    t.state_id = t1.rnd,
    t.closed_on = if(t1.rnd = 3, null, current_date)
```

Comment: yeah I just thought of this :)

Comment: I think I'll do this way!